# Django admin panel missing management form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, formset

The following exception occurs on admin panel while trying to change an object type (say a product), but it only occurs on SOME of them. I can't seem to debug this, where should I be inspecting? I'm not instantiating custom forms and formsets so I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Do you have any ideas where I should be inspecting?

How can I know if the management form is rendered at all? I've saved the HTML source of the product change form.

```
Traceback:

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py" in wrapper
  499.                 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1512.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1448.             if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in all_valid
  456.         if not formset.is_valid():

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in is_valid
  321.         self.errors

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in errors
  295.             self.full_clean()

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in full_clean
  342.         for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in total_form_count
  116.             return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)

File "/website/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in management_form
  98.                     code='missing_management_form',

Exception Type: ValidationError at /panel/marketplace/product/2576979/change/
Exception Value: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Comment: Could you share your `admin.py`?